# XSLT 1.0 Concatenate Random value in order

Tags: loops, xslt, concatenation

I am new to XSLT and I am trying to solve this problem. I have to get some values from the XML and concatenate them. Whenever I am trying to do that I am getting only one value but I want all 4 values in my result. The XML values can be in any order but I want the result in the particular format only. The result should be Tag61 value+Tag9F01 value+Tag81 value+Tag4F value (Please ignore + sign).

Please find the XML below

```
<Transaction_details> 
<Transaction> 
<Detail> 
<tag>9F01</tag> 
<tag_value>9F01020001</tag_value>   
</Detail> 
<Detail> 
<tag>9F40</tag> 
<tag_value>9F40020001</tag_value>   
</Detail> 
<Detail> 
<tag>9F021</tag> 
<tag_value>9F021020001</tag_value>  
</Detail> 
<Detail> 
<tag>81</tag> 
<tag_value>81020001</tag_value> 
</Detail> 
<Detail> 
<tag>9F44</tag> 
<tag_value>9F44020001</tag_value>   
</Detail> 
<Detail> 
<tag>94</tag> 
<tag_value>94020001</tag_value> 
</Detail> 
<Detail> 
<tag>4F</tag> 
<tag_value>4F1020001</tag_value>    
</Detail> 
<Detail> 
<tag>61</tag> 
<tag_value>61020001</tag_value> 
</Detail> 
</Transaction>  
</Transaction_details>
```

The code I have written

```
<xsl:for-each select="Transaction_details/Transaction"> 
<xsl:variable name="TAG"> 
<xsl:value-of select="Detail/tag"/> 
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:variable name="TotalTags"> 
<xsl:variable name="Tag61"> 
<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test="$TAG='61'"> 
<xsl:value-of select="Detail/tag_value"/> 
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:otherwise> 
<xsl:value-of select="'No Data'"/> 
</xsl:otherwise>    
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:variable name="Tag9F01"> 
<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test="$TAG='9F01'"> 
<xsl:value-of select="Detail/tag_value"/> 
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:otherwise> 
<xsl:value-of select="'No Data'"/> 
</xsl:otherwise>    
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:variable name="Tag81"> 
<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test="$TAG='81'"> 
<xsl:value-of select="Detail/tag_value"/> 
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:otherwise> 
<xsl:value-of select="'No Data'"/> 
</xsl:otherwise>    
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:variable name="Tag4F"> 
<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test="$TAG='4F'"> 
<xsl:value-of select="Detail/tag_value"/> 
</xsl:when> 
<xsl: otherwise> 
<xsl:value-of select="'No Data'"/> 
</xsl:otherwise>    
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Tag61,$Tag9F01,$Tag81,$Tag4F)"/>  
</xsl:variable> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

After this code when I am concatenating the values I am getting only 1 value. 
I am using XSLT 1.0. Could some one please advice how to achieve the desired result. Which one good option recursive template or for_each to solve this problem?

thank you in advance,

Kaushik

Comment: "*I am getting only one value*" No, you are not. With the code you have posted, you are not getting *any* value. Even after correcting the syntax errors, all you're doing is write to variables - you are not actually outputting anything. It's also not clear what is the actual result you want to get. Please edit your question and add the exact **code** you expect to see as the result of the transformation.

Comment: Hi,
Please ignore the code I have written. Could you please suggest me some code which will give me the concatenated tag_value node value of tag 61, 9F01, 81 and 4F?
thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **exact code** you expect to see as the result of the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight a couple of issues with you XSLT, one issue is where you define your `TAG` variable

```
<xsl:variable name="TAG"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="Detail/tag"/> 
</xsl:variable>
```

This will set `TAG` to be a single string containing the value of the first `Detail/tag` only. You probably should have done this

```
<xsl:variable name="TAG" select="Detail/tag"/>
```

This then sets `TAG` to a node-set of all `Detail/tag` records.

Similarly, when you do a test, you did this

```
<xsl:when test="$TAG='61'"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="Detail/tag_value"/> 
</xsl:when>
```

This will output only the first `Detail/tag_value` value, not the one for tag `61`.

But to keep things short, your XSLT can be initially re-written as this

```
<xsl:template match="Transaction_details/Transaction">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail[tag='61']/tag_value" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail[tag='9F01']/tag_value" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail[tag='81']/tag_value" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail[tag='4F']/tag_value" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note you don't actually need a template matching `tag_value` here, as the built-in templates will just be used to output the text.

This will only work if the tags are always present. Although you don't actually mention it in your question, it looks like you want to output "No Data" if a tag doesn't exist.

To do this, and avoid repetitive coding, you could use a named template. Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Transaction_details/Transaction">
        <xsl:call-template name="TagValue"><xsl:with-param name="tag" select="'61'" /></xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="TagValue"><xsl:with-param name="tag" select="'9F01'" /></xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="TagValue"><xsl:with-param name="tag" select="'81'" /></xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="TagValue"><xsl:with-param name="tag" select="'4F'" /></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="TagValue">
        <xsl:param name="tag" />
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="Detail[tag=$tag]/tag_value" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
        <xsl:if test="not($value)">No Data</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please ignore the code I have written. Could you please suggest me
>   some code which will give me the concatenated tag_value node value of
>   tag 61, 9F01, 81 and 4F?

Your question is still not quite clear, but if you want to concatenate the `tag_value` values of all `Detail`s tagged with one of the 4 listed tags, you can so very simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Transaction_details">
    <xsl:for-each select="Transaction/Detail[tag='61' or tag='9F01' or tag='81' or tag='4F']" >
        <xsl:value-of select="tag_value"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **result** in your example will be:

```
9F01020001810200014F102000161020001
```